WiFi show a off word blinking when wifi is pressed off and using mobile carrier network
WiFi show a off word blinking in menu when wifi is pressed off and using mobile carrier network
what does it mean ? is it malware infected ? is it hacked by mobile carrier network?
i checked that wifi scanning is off and other wifi options are also off
why wifi word show off blinking in android 12 CAT phone S42

Based on your description is difficult to understand where "off" word is shown in a blinking state. best would be a screen shot of the phone, e.g. using Android's built-in screen shot function.

touch drop down list , Below wifi has a word on and off, to show whether wifi on or off. the off word become blinking in android.

I ca only repeat, please create and post a screenshot. Your description is not clear, especially as the installed Android OS may be modified by the manufacturer thus the blinking Wifi function may only exist on your phone model.
